# Tkinter display unicode char in Button text

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display a unicode character on a button as text .
In tkinter I can display a unicode character using `text=u"\u00f7"`

```
b = Button(master,text=u"\u00f7", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()
```

But I wish to create a list of unicode characters and then pass it to the Button widget in tkinter through a for loop.

```
 from Tkinter import *

 master =Tk()
 upper=["\u00f7","\u00f7","\u00f7"]
 key_var1=100
 key_var2=150
 keypad_bttn=[]
 for k in range(0,3):
                keypad_bttn.append(Button(master, text = upper[k],))
                keypad_bttn[k].place(x=key_var1,y=key_var2)
                key_var1=key_var1+40


 master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, you have a unicode string, `u"\u00f7"`, in the second example you have regular strings, `"\u00f7"`. Notice the missing `u` before the string in the second example.

You should use

```
upper=[u"\u00f7",u"\u00f7",u"\u00f7"]
```